# Lenovo x2XX tablet auto-rotate rotates main screen (not internal one)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, tablet, tablet-mode

I have a Lenovo x230t with Windows 10. I use the autorotate feature which generally works nicely.
However, it seems to rotate always the primary monitor instead of the internal monitor which is pretty terrible.

When my tablet is in the dock and I flip the display (which frequently changes because I use it as a secondary monitor as well as tablet) it rotates my external monitor (which is set as as primary monitor).

Is there any way to prevent this?

How does this autorotate feature work and where is it implemented? Is there any hack that allows me to execute a program/script instead? (like iRotate.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch for this:

- http://niki.hammler.net/w/images/a/a5/LenovoAutoRotatorPatch.zip

It replaces `ScreenRotation.exe` with a version that rotates the first display (which is always the internal one).